# Arduino-uno midi notes playing incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, midi, arduino-uno

I am designing an arduino-uno based electronic harp using LDRs as the strings (when the LDR is pressed the note plays). It is midi based. It currently has four LDRs that play the correct notes when pressed. I am trying to make it play a different note when two LDRs are pressed to expand the range. This works when I have the code for one pair of LDRs but when I add code for a second it sounds extremely wrong, playing a growling sound.

This is the code for one pair of LDRs:

```
for (nt=0;nt<notes;nt++) 
  {
      val[nt]=analogRead(Det[nt]);
      delay(1);

      if (val[0]<threshold[1]&&val[1]<threshold[1]){
            if(prev_nts[nt] == false) {
              digitalWrite(LED[0], HIGH);  //TURN led ON if value below threshold
              digitalWrite(LED[1], HIGH);
              noteOn(0, music[0], vol[nt]); //note (middle number) 40-62, (channel, pitch, volume from array)
              prev_nts[nt] = true;
            }}
      else {
          digitalWrite(LED[0], LOW);
          digitalWrite(LED[1], LOW);
          //TURN led OFF if value below threshold
          noteOff(0, music[0], 0); //note (middle number) 40-62
          prev_nts[nt] = false;
        }
}
```

This is my code for two pairs of LDRs:

```
for (nt=0;nt<notes;nt++) 
  {
      val[nt]=analogRead(Det[nt]);
      delay(1);

      if (val[0]<threshold[1]&&val[1]<threshold[1]){
            if(prev_nts[nt] == false) {
              digitalWrite(LED[0], HIGH);  //TURN led ON if value below threshold
              digitalWrite(LED[1], HIGH);
              noteOn(0, music[0], vol[nt]); //note (middle number) 40-62, (channel, pitch, volume from array)
              prev_nts[nt] = true;
            }}
      else {
          digitalWrite(LED[0], LOW);
          digitalWrite(LED[1], LOW);
          //TURN led OFF if value below threshold
          noteOff(0, music[0], 0); //note (middle number) 40-62
          prev_nts[nt] = false;
        }


      if (val[2]<threshold[2]&&val[3]<threshold[3]){
            if(prev_nts[nt] == false) {
              digitalWrite(LED[2], HIGH);  //TURN led ON if value below threshold
              digitalWrite(LED[3], HIGH);
              noteOn(0, music[1], vol[nt]); //note (middle number) 40-62, (channel, pitch, volume from array)
              prev_nts[nt] = true;
            }}
      else {
          digitalWrite(LED[2], LOW);
          digitalWrite(LED[3], LOW);
          //TURN led OFF if value below threshold
          noteOff(0, music[1], 0); //note (middle number) 40-62
          prev_nts[nt] = false;
        }
```

}

This is my whole code:

```
// 4 channel photodetector and LED indicator. 
// Kate Sugden, August 2017

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

//  pins for photodetectors and LED indicators
  byte ledPin = 13; //MIDI traffic inidicator

  int Det[] = {A0,A1,A2,A3};  // defines Detecotr pins
  int LED[] = {11,10,9,8};  // defines LED indicator pins
  int notes = 4;              //number of notes in harp
  int val []  = {0,0,0,0};   // sets all the values of the detector readings to zero - need as many as notes
  int threshold []  = {0,0,0,0}; 
  boolean prev_nts[] = {false,false,false,false};
  int music[] = {48,50,52,53};
  boolean notePressed = false;


// defined delays and thresholds
  int nt = 0;   // note number
  int timer = 10;  // delay option


//MIDI
  byte note = 0; //The MIDI note value to be played
  byte resetMIDI = 4; //Tied to VS1053 Reset line
 // int  instrument = 118; //Harp is 47, 80 Ocarina, 46 Pizzicato strings (most convincing) percussion 36, 118 synth drum
 int instrument[] = {118,117,49,115};
 int definst=46; //default instrument
 int vol[]={100,100,100,100}; //sets volume (127 is max)

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Serial.begin(31250);

  // we make all the declarations at once
  for (nt=0;nt<notes;nt++) 
    {
      pinMode(Det[nt], INPUT);   //declares detectors
      pinMode(LED[nt], OUTPUT);  //declares indicators
      val[nt]=analogRead(Det[nt]); //this reads the LDR values once
      threshold[nt]=val[nt]-20; // this then calculates a threshold value for each channel based on starting ambient light and sets the threshold X below this. .
    }

  //this bit configures the midi
  mySerial.begin(31250);
  pinMode(resetMIDI, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(resetMIDI, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(resetMIDI, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  talkMIDI(0xB0, 0x07, vol[0]); //0xB0 is channel message, set channel volume (3rd number) to near max (127)
  talkMIDI(0xB0, 0, 0x79);
  talkMIDI(0xC0, definst, 0);
}

void loop()

{   
  for (nt=0;nt<notes;nt++) 
  {
val[nt]=analogRead(Det[nt]);
      delay(1);

      if (val[0]<threshold[1]&&val[1]<threshold[1]){
            if(prev_nts[nt] == false) {
              digitalWrite(LED[0], HIGH);  //TURN led ON if value below threshold
              digitalWrite(LED[1], HIGH);
              noteOn(0, music[0], vol[nt]); //note (middle number) 40-62, (channel, pitch, volume from array)
              prev_nts[nt] = true;
            }}
      else {
          digitalWrite(LED[0], LOW);
          digitalWrite(LED[1], LOW);
          //TURN led OFF if value below threshold
          noteOff(0, music[0], 0); //note (middle number) 40-62
          prev_nts[nt] = false;
        }


      if (val[2]<threshold[2]&&val[3]<threshold[3]){
            Serial.println(notePressed); //never reaching here
            if(prev_nts[nt] == false) {
              digitalWrite(LED[2], HIGH);  //TURN led ON if value below threshold
              digitalWrite(LED[3], HIGH);
              noteOn(0, music[1], vol[nt]); //note (middle number) 40-62, (channel, pitch, volume from array)
              prev_nts[nt] = true;
            }}
      else {
          digitalWrite(LED[2], LOW);
          digitalWrite(LED[3], LOW);
          //TURN led OFF if value below threshold
          noteOff(0, music[1], 0); //note (middle number) 40-62
          prev_nts[nt] = false;
        }
}
}

void noteOn(byte channel, byte note, byte attack_velocity) {
  talkMIDI( (0x90 | channel), note, attack_velocity);
}
//Send a MIDI note-off message.  Like releasing a piano key
void noteOff(byte channel, byte note, byte release_velocity) {
  talkMIDI( (0x80 | channel), note, release_velocity);
}
void talkMIDI(byte cmd, byte data1, byte data2) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  mySerial.write(cmd);
  mySerial.write(data1);
//Some commands only have one data byte. All cmds less than 0xBn have 2 data bytes 
//(sort of: http://253.ccarh.org/handout/midiprotocol/)
  if( (cmd & 0xF0) <= 0xB0)
    mySerial.write(data2);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

This is also my first time programming using arduino, so I may not be aware of simple mistakes. I usually program in Java and Python.

Comment: Not sure I get this. You say it works fine for one pair of LDRs but doesn't work when you add a second. Do you mean a second pair, i.e. 4 LDRs in total?

Comment: yes, there are 4 LDRs total

Comment: In `talkMIDI()` you test `cmd & 0xF0 <= 0xB0` . Should that actually be `>=`?

Comment: What are you actually playing it through, btw?

Comment: I just tested with >= and it didn't play any sound. It is a simple amplifier

Comment: I can't find any amplifiers with MIDI inputs...

Comment: I would have thought you would want to immediately do 4 `analogRead()s` at the start of each loop and then decide what to do when you have them all. Otherwise you read `val[0]` only and then decide what to do partially based on `val[1]` through `val[3]` which you have yet to read.